# How do you segment an image containing text?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

I have an image containing text and I want to cut each letter from the image. How would I achieve this using MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With the Image Processing Toolbox

If you have the toolbox you can quickly identify each separate letter in your image.

Starting with a gray scale image you have to find a segmentation threshold with

```
level = graythresh(Img);
```

Then convert the image to binary with

```
Img = im2bw(Img,level);
```

With

```
Cc = bwconncomp(Img);
```

you get a structure that contains the linear indices of each identified component in its field

```
Cc.PixelIdxList
```

See the documentation for those functions to adjust the segmentation to your needs.

### Without the Image Processing Toolbox

You have to implement the connected component algorithm yourself.

From the Matlab documentation:

```
>The basic steps in finding the connected components are:
>
>1. Search for the next unlabeled pixel, p.
>2. Use a flood-fill algorithm to label all the pixels in the connected component containing p.
>3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until all the pixels are labeled.
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be to test for the color:

Find out which color the letters have.

Suppose this is your image, containing a letter T written in color 5:

```
myImage = round(4*rand(6));
myImage(1:2,:) = 5; %Drawing the top bar of the T
myImage(:,3:4) = 5; %Drawing the leg of the t
myColor = 5;
```

Now to only keep the letter(/letters):

```
myImage(myImage~=myColor) = NaN
```

Now you can plot it using

```
surf(myImage)
```

It is not too hard to extend this to a color range (or to a set of RGB colors, depending on what kind of format your image is)

Comment: @طالبةعلم I have extended my example to be a bit more meaningful, now it actually contains a letter.